# navigator.platform equivalent in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, compatibility, navigator, platform

In JavaScript there is the *navigator.platform* property, is there an equivalent to this for PHP which will always return the same results as *navigator.platform* will in JavaScript?

Example I want to recreate in PHP

https://privatebin.net/?a1de9338efd2f741#GeSTRqsU1oMtGRu5634KLec5RgVSAFkD8GZr5peiPs4U

Comment: Are you trying to get the *server* OS or the *client* OS?  In either case, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: No. You can grab the user agent string and parse that out to get similar information, but you won't get the same results.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM']` but be aware that these values can be spoofed.

Comment: @David

I have used this with JavaScript to determine if a device is using ios or not and it been useful. I would like to rewrite it the same way in PHP but I been unable to find out how to get the *navigator.platform* in PHP. I added some code in the OP

Comment: @janeperritson: If you want information about the client browser/platform/etc. then what you're looking for is the "user agent".  Keep in mind of course that clients can spoof this, so don't trust it for anything security-related.  But for anything UX-related it tells you what the client allows you to know about the browser/platform/etc.

Comment: @nice_dev
 This works on Chrome but not Firefox. Explains why I did not see this  earlier but it is not the same results as using navigator.platform in JS

Comment: @janeperritson You won't be getting exact strings sometimes and would require some extra effort.

Comment: Why does PHP care if a device is using IOS?  Is this for analytics?  You could send the browser's `navigator.platform` value via a request to php, if you need it desperately.

Comment: Agreed, why exactly does your PHP code need to know what O/S the client making a request was using? One of the great things about HTTP is that it really doesn't matter what O/S, programming language, platform etc the the client and server are running - as long as they both speak HTTP, they can talk to each other. As James mentioned, I can't think of another reason except perhaps for logging some sort of analytics.